# Qt : send AT command to GPRS modem

Tags: c++, qt, modem, gprs, qtserialport

I have an Arduino board with a GPRS shield. I'm able to send and receive SMS's with Arduino's IDE, but I'm about to use a Wavecom GPRS modem now.

I can connect and send strings from Qt to Arduino board so that when Arduino receives a special string from Qt, it sends an SMS. See code below.

But now, I'm stuck... don't know how to send AT commands directly from Qt and not just sending a string that Arduino's waiting for to send an SMS...

Does someone now if it's possible to send AT commands from Qt to a GPRS modem?

Arduino code:

```
void  loop()
{
    //Check if available
    if (Serial.available())
    {
        // read the incoming byte:
        incomingByte = Serial.read();

       //Just to show how it works
       if(incomingByte == 'X')
       {
        AT commands to send an sms
        }    
   }
    else
        delay(5); // there is nothing to read, so wait a few msec's
}
```

Comment: How is that different from the Arduino board? QIODevice::write() abstracts this out all if you use the QSerialPort class, provided that the GPRS's modem AT communication happens via serial port hardware interface.

Comment: I hope I'm wrong, but I'm only able to send a signal from Qt to Arduino who's listening for a signal (In my case a string). When he gets the signal he send the SMS with AT commands who are in the Arduino board. I'm not able to put any data in a GPRS modem...

I was looking for QProcess class to execute a shell script sending AT commands, but still hope it's possible to do it directly from Qt

Comment: How do you think AT commands work? In my experience, they are sent over regular serial port in general. Now, it might be the case that you have some bluetooth, etc, modem, but based on your serial usage, it will likely be serial. There is no tight connection between the modem and your Qt program on the other. I am not sure why you think two programs can only talk if they are both written in Qt, etc.

Comment: Just discovered you could put AT commands: `m_serialPort->write(QByteArray("AT..\r\n"));`

That would save my day!!

Comment: Because I'm far away being a pro ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AT` commands are usually sent via serial port that will be processed by the controller software on the GPRS modem. Therefore, you only need to take care of the sending side in your Qt application.

Thereby, you would just use the `QIODevice::write()` interface through the QtSerialPort module:

```
mySerialPort->write("My AT command");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! :)  
I think this is gonna work with a "normal" modem, but with Arduino commands are as following: `SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");` because there's a shield -SIM900- on it.

This doesn't work...
mySerialPort->write("SIM900.print(\"AT+CMGF=1\r\")\r\n");
Don't see how to face that